# Trouble reading a netcdf file and convert it into a SpatRaster

Tags: r, r-raster

I am struggling to open a NetCDF file and *convert* it into a raster using R. The
data is supposed to be on a regular grid of 25 km by 25 km. It contains sea
ice concentration in the Arctic.

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.5.21
library(ncdf4)

file <- "~/Downloads/data_sat_Phil_changt_grid/SIC_SMMR_month_2015.nc"
```

I am getting a warning about the extent not found.

```r
r <- rast(file)
#> Error in R_nc4_open: No such file or directory
#> Warning: [rast] GDAL did not find an extent. Cells not equally spaced?
```

We can see that there is a problem with the coordinates/extent.

```r
r
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 448, 304, 12  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.003289474, 0.002232143  (x, y)
#> extent      : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#> source      : SIC_SMMR_month_2015.nc:sic 
#> varname     : sic 
#> names       : sic_1, sic_2, sic_3, sic_4, sic_5, sic_6, ...
```

I can open the nc file with `nc_open()` and I see that the coordinates are present.

```r
nc <- nc_open(file)
names(nc$var)
#> [1] "lat" "lon" "sic"

lat <- ncvar_get(nc, "lat")
lon <- ncvar_get(nc, "lon")

dim(lat)
#> [1] 304 448
dim(lon)
#> [1] 304 448
dim(r)
#> [1] 448 304  12
```

Is it possible to assemble this data (the SIC values and the coordinates) to create a `SpatRaster`?
The nc file can be downloaded here: https://easyupload.io/pfth0s

<sup>Created on 2022-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: try  project(rast(file), rast())  - if that *works*, it means that GDAL recognizes the lon/lat arrays as GEOLOCATION metadata, and can push it through the warper - build a target rast() to match whatever grid you want (and makes sense given the extent and resolution of the data)

Comment: but, Robert's answer is better in this case - the data under the hood is projected, it's very hard to determine the difference automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data are gridded, but the file does not specify the coordinates, nor the coordinate reference system. The file specifies the lon/lat values associated with the cells, but does not help us much, as these are clearly not on a regular grid. That is easy to see from `plot(r)`

```
NAflag(r) = -9999
plot(r,1)
```

[image]

And also from

```
p = cbind(as.vector(lon), as.vector(lat))
plot(p, cex=.1, xlab="lon", ylab="lat")
```

[image]

So what you need to find out, is which coordinate reference system (crs) is used, clearly some kind of polar crs. And what the extent of the data set is.

From the website you point to, I take it we can use:

```
crs(r) = "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=70 +lon_0=-45 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378273 +b=6356889.449 +units=m +no_defs"
ext(r) = c(-3850000, 3750000, -5350000, 5850000)
r
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 448, 304, 12  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 25000, 25000  (x, y)
#extent      : -3850000, 3750000, -5350000, 5850000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=70 +lon_0=-45 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378273 +b=6356889.449 +units=m +no_defs 
#source      : SIC_SMMR_month_2015.nc:sic 
#varname     : sic 
#names       : sic_1, sic_2, sic_3, sic_4, sic_5, sic_6, ...
```

The results look good:

```
g = geodata::gadm("Greenland", level=0, path=".")
gg = project(g, crs(r))
plot(r,1)
lines(gg)
```

[image]

But this is of course not a good way to do such things; the ncdf file should have contained all the metadata required.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The original data is from NSIDC (https://nsidc.org/data/NSIDC-0079). Based on the documentation, it looks like it is polar stereo (https://nsidc.org/data/polar-stereo).

Comment: That helps, but this is not a terrible way to share data.

Comment: Thank you very much @Robert. Your detailed comments made me learn a lot, actually. I will contact the persons who give me the data so they better store the geographical information. Thank you again, very much appreciated.