# What is causing this raster reprojection error?

Tags: r, gis, raster

Following up this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72321967/trouble-reading-a-netcdf-file-and-convert-it-into-a-spatraster), I was able to convert a netcdf into a raster object. However, I have found that I could not reproject this raster into another coordinate system. I have searched around based on the error message (see below), but could not find much information.

Any idea?

The data is still available here: https://easyupload.io/pfth0s

Regards,
Phil

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.5.21
r <- rast("SIC_SMMR_month_2015.nc")
#> Error in R_nc4_open: No such file or directory
#> Warning: [rast] GDAL did not find an extent. Cells not equally spaced?

crs(r) <- "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=70 +lon_0=-45 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378273 +b=6356889.449 +units=m +no_defs"
ext(r) <-  c(-3850000, 3750000, -5350000, 5850000)
NAflag(r) <- -9999

plot(r, 1)
```

[image]

```r
project(r, "EPSG:3408")
#> Warning: The transformation is already "north up" or a transformation between
#> pixel/line and georeferenced coordinates cannot be computed for NETCDF:"SIC_SMMR_month_2015.nc":sic. There is no affine transformation and no GCPs.
#> Specify transformation option SRC_METHOD=NO_GEOTRANSFORM to bypass this check.
#> (GDAL error 1)
#> Error: [project] cannot get output boundaries
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

EDIT:

I have found out that it works if I use `project(..., gdal = FALSE)`, but I am not sure if it is an appropriate solution.

Comment: How did you find the "right" extent?

Comment: In the answer to the question you refer to (although not elaborated much). What you used is an approximation that is not *right*.

Comment: Is there something on my side? I do not see any answers.

Comment: I did not answer this question, but I (and you) referred to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72321967/635245

Comment: Sorry, was confused for a moment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It does look good

```
library(terra)
r <- rast("SIC_SMMR_month_2015.nc")
#Error in R_nc4_open: Invalid argument
#Warning message:
#[rast] GDAL did not find an extent. Cells not equally spaced? 
#> Error in R_nc4_open: No such file or directory
#> Warning: [rast] GDAL did not find an extent. Cells not equally spaced?
crs(r) <- "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=70 +lon_0=-45 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378273 +b=6356889.449 +units=m +no_defs"
ext(r) <-  c(-3850000, 3750000, -5350000, 5850000)
NAflag(r) <- -9999

g <- geodata::gadm("Greenland", level=0, path=".")
grn <- project(g, "EPSG:3408")
p <- project(r, "EPSG:3408", gdal=F)

# there are a few high values add the edges
x <- clamp(p, 0, 1)

plot(x, 1)
lines(grn)
```

[image]

I have not (yet) investigated the source of this problem

```
p <- project(r, "EPSG:3408")
#Error: [project] cannot get output boundaries
#In addition: Warning message:
#The transformation is already "north up" or a transformation between
# pixel/line and georeferenced coordinates cannot be computed for
# NETCDF:"C:/Users/rhijm/Downloads/SIC_SMMR_month_2015.nc":sic. There is no
# affine transformation and no GCPs. Specify transformation option
# SRC_METHOD=NO_GEOTRANSFORM to bypass this check. (GDAL error 1)
```

And I do not know if there is a better solution. The situation is even worse when you provide a template raster as second argument. In that case R crashes. So this does merit some research.

Comment: Thank you for validating. Maybe should an issue opened on the package repo.

Comment: I think that is a good idea